# Ubuntu Precise 12.04 Kernel Headers

Tags: 12.04, wireless, kernel

Recently, on my installation of Ubuntu Precise 12.04.3 on my Beaglebone Black, while tying to install some Wifi drivers, it says it requires kernel headers.
The kernel version is 3.8.13-bone30 (from uname -r), but I have no idea how to get the right kernel headers. I have done a bit of searching and there doesn't seem to be much, if anything, to go on.
So could anyone help me out as to how to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Note quite sure what the `bone30` is. Is it a self compiled kernel? If not, where did you get it from.

Comment: Its the default kernel when one installs the Ubuntu Precise image from these instructions http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:Ubuntu_On_BeagleBone_Black#Ubuntu_Precise_On_Micro_SD

Comment: The first sentence on beagleboard.org reads: The Linux kernel sources for the BeagleBoard, BeagleBoard-xM and BeagleBone are maintained on [Github.com/BeagleBoard](https://github.com/beagleboard) :-)

Comment: So can I download the headers from there?

Comment: Sure you can, in case they privide the headers. It seems to be a separate project with private packages from non-ubuntu repositoreis. ... likely off topic here, as we can't possibly support every respin of an ubuntu kernel.

Comment: Is this what you need? http://rcn-ee.net/deb/precise-armhf/v3.8.13-bone30/

Comment: cool i think thats what i need! ill give it a try. but where do i install them to?

Answer (score 0):

As the 3.8 kernel is originally from Raring (13.04), you should try installing `linux-headers-generic-lts-raring`, which will pull in the latest headers. In short:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic-lts-raring
```

Comment: hmm... doesnt seem to work... im trying to use "backports" to patch some wifi drivers, and i get this:
Your kernel headers are incomplete/not installed.
Please install kernel headers, including a .config
file or use the KLIB/KLIB_BUILD make variables to
set the kernel to build against, e.g.
make KLIB=/lib/modules/3.1.7/
to compile/install for the installed kernel 3.1.7
(that isn't currently running.)
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 1
make: *** [default] Error 2